# ng-repeat is not populating <info-window>

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, angularjs-directive

I am using the [angularjs-google-maps](https://github.com/allenhwkim/angularjs-google-maps) directive in my application, and it's been working just fine till now.

I am trying to show the `Item`s a `Shop` have in a `<info-window>`. However, the `ng-repeat` is not being filled, and I cannot figure why.

```
<map>

    <div ng-repeat="shop in shops">

        <marker id="{{shop.shop_name}}" 
                position="{{shop.position}}" 
                title="{{shop.shop_name}}"
                on-click="showInfoWindow(event, shop.id)"></marker>

        <info-window id="{{shop.id}}" visible-on-marker="{{$index}}">
            <div style="width: 500px; height: 300px;">
                {{ shop.shop_name }} <br />

                {{ shop.items[0].name }}

                <!-- This line is not working -->
                <div ng-repeat="item in shop.items">{{$index}}|{{item.name}}</div>

                <div class="clear"></div>
            </div>
        </info-window>

    </div>

</map>
```

Why are the `ng-repeat` not populating data in the `<info-window>`?

Comment: Is {{ shop.items[0].name }} showing anything? Is it not appearing on screen or also not in the rendered html?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's nothing obvious wrong with your code, because given

```
$scope.shops = [{
  id: 1,
  name: 'name1',
  items: [1,2]
},{
  id: 2,
  name: 'name2',
  items:[3,4,5]
}];
```

Then HTML template

```
<div ng-controller="" class="ng-scope">
  <map center="" zoom="">
    <info-window id="1" position="">
      <div ng-non-bindable="">
        <div ng-repeat="shop in shops">
          <div>
            shop id:{{ shop.id }} name:{{shop.name}}
          </div>
          <div ng-repeat="item in shop.items">
            item:{{ item }}
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </info-window>
  </map>
</div>
```

Gives you

[image: imgur]

Related plunker here http://plnkr.co/edit/kJvhCX

Comment: This does work **outside** the `info-window`, however, not inside

Comment: Edited the answer. You need to wrap your content around `<div ng-non-bindable=""></div>`

Comment: Your plunker doesn't work anymore. Another question that I don't get in is how the binding is supposed to work if there is ng-non-bindable wrapper?

Comment: Seems like ngMap project has changed a bit,  `ng-non-bindable` was working workaround before.